# unordered_map: which one is faster find() or count()?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, unordered-map

What is the fastest way to figure out if an `unordered_map` container has an item with a specified key?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

They will have about equal performance. You should use the algorithm that best expresses what you are trying to do.

To elaborate on that, generally `count()` will be implemented using `find()`. For example, in [libcxx](http://libcxx.llvm.org), `count()` is implemented as `return (find(__k) != end());`

Answer (score 12):

C++20 ended the dilemma by providing `contains` method, which still has the same performance, but directly says what you mean.

Comment: Is the source code of `contains` exactly the `count`'s?

Comment: @Eric, implementation is up to the implementation, one might call another, or both may contain equivalent representation

Answer (score 6):

`find()` and `count()` are applicable to many containers in C++.

For maps, sets etc. `find()` will always have constant execution time, since it just calculate the hash, and returns an iterator to the first element found (`end()` if not found).

`count()` on the other hand, has a constant execution time O(e), where e is the number of times the provided key is found. The worst case is a collection where all members are the same, so `count()` could have a complexity O(n)

`map` or `unordered_map` do not allow for duplicates, therefore their asymptotic run time would be the same.

The choice depends on the semantics in your code. If you want just to check if a key exist, you could just use `count`. If you would like to check if a key exists, and use its value, then go for `find` since you will already have an iterator pointing to that element.

Comment: This is not true. You are saying that `find()` would return a pointer even if the actual searched value does not exist, but there is a hash collision for it.

Comment: A better objection would be that "always have constant execution time" is not true because that is amortised and best-case, but in the worst case lookup can be linear time, i.e. it tends towards that as the proportion of hash collisions increases. Another, if more pedantic, objection would be that this only applies to *unordered* maps and sets; those not adorned thusly are ordered and (usually) slower.

Answer (score -1):

"by website cplusplus" there is a difference between for time complexity:

`unordered_map::count -> O` (number of counted)

`map::count -> O(log)`

So you should use unordered_map to faster

Comment: The original question doesn't ask about a difference in computational complexity of certain methods between `unordered_map` and `map`. It asks which method is faster to find a key in the same data structure. I'm afraid your comment is not quite relevant.