# In unordered_set, which is faster for find and count, and what effect does compiler optimization have on their efficiency?

Tags: c++, stl

I have seen a similar link before I asked a question.
[unordered_map: which one is faster find() or count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159682/unordered-map-which-one-is-faster-find-or-count)

But the answer under this question did not convince me.
I checked the SGI STL source code. There may be different implementations, but I think it will be more similar.
 the find and count functtion are there:

```
  iterator find(const key_type& __key) 
  {
    size_type __n = _M_bkt_num_key(__key);
    _Node* __first;
    for ( __first = _M_buckets[__n];
          __first && !_M_equals(_M_get_key(__first->_M_val), __key);
          __first = __first->_M_next)
      {}
    return iterator(__first, this);
  } 

  size_type count(const key_type& __key) const
  {
    const size_type __n = _M_bkt_num_key(__key);
    size_type __result = 0;

    for (const _Node* __cur = _M_buckets[__n]; __cur; __cur = __cur->_M_next)
      if (_M_equals(_M_get_key(__cur->_M_val), __key))
        ++__result;
    return __result;
  }
```

According to the above code, assuming that the target we are looking for has a 50% probability of being in the unordered_set, then I think that find will be more efficient than count, because count will traverse to the end each time.
In order to verify my guess, I did the following experiment.
code show as below:

```
   const int64_t test_count = 100;
   const int64_t set_size = 100000;
   unordered_set<int64_t> test_set;
   for (auto i = 0; i < set_size; ++i) test_set.emplace(i * 2);
   StopWatch sw;
   int64_t fc = 0;
   for (auto t = 0; t < test_count; ++t) {
     for (auto i = 0; i < set_size; ++i) {
       if (test_set.count(i) > 0) {
         ++fc;
       }
     }
   }
   float spend_time = sw.GetLapMsec();
   cout << "count fc:" << fc << ", t:" << spend_time << endl;
   sw.Reset();
   fc = 0;
   for (auto t = 0; t < test_count; ++t) {
     for (auto i = 0; i < set_size; ++i) {
       if (test_set.end() != test_set.find(i)) {
         ++fc;
       }
     }
   }
   spend_time = sw.GetLapMsec();
   cout << " find fc:" << fc << ", t:" << spend_time << endl;
```

build and run:
`g++ -o t1.out -g main.cpp -std=c++11 -O0 && ./t1.out`

But the result is beyond my expectation:

```
count fc:5000000, t:1084.74
 find fc:5000000, t:1300.51
```

The find is slower then count!

Then I change the -O param with -O1 to turn on compiler optimization, the result is changed to:

```
count fc:5000000, t:216.555
 find fc:5000000, t:173.871
```

Both count and find are much faster than before. More importantly, the relationship between count and find has changed. Find has become faster than count.

So when the compiler is not optimized, why is find slower than count, and how does compiler optimization affect their efficiency, can someone tell me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your timings are off, as you're including a bunch of output time in your timings.  The `sw.GetLapMsec()` call _must_ come before any output (before any uses of `cout`) to ensure a more accurate count.

Comment: This is just a random guess (hence not putting this out as an answer), but this could be due to the binary ABI. If `_M_equals` could possibly return only 0 or 1, then `count()`'s `if` statement can get optimized away completely by simply adding the return value from `_M_equals` to `__result`. And this is something I can see happening even with all optimizations turned off. Branching is notorious for having wild performance impact on modern CPUs due to branch prediction, and eliminating a branch can have notable performance impact, and the stars aligning just right to make `count` faster.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Oh, I didn't notice this place before, I modified the code again, retested and updated the test result data, thank you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Thanks for the reply, I looked at the code, _M_equals default version is std::equal_to<T>, it's member function operator() return type is bool, can that achieve the kind of optimization you said? After the compiler optimization is turned on, this advantage is gone, even more strange.

Comment: Regarding "traverse to the end each time": an unordered set performs best (more or less) when each bucket has at most one element in it. Have you done any checking to see how big the buckets are in your test?

Comment: @JaMiT, Thank you for prompt, and I just check the number of buckets and found that it is 126271. There seems to be no function to get the number of each bucket. But according to the code of find and count, even if there is only one data in each bucket, count has no advantage.

Comment: @echoonly That's not entirely accurate. According to the code of `find` and `count`, there is a task that `find` does and that `count` does not, specifically constructing (and returning) an iterator. The time for this task might be negligible, but based solely on the code you presented, it is a theoretical advantage for `count`.

Comment: @JaMiT, Oh, what you said makes sense, this is indeed the job done by find more than count, this may cause the count to be faster. I try to verify it with experiments.